# Improve round robin tournament to play on different tables

Tags: java, algorithm

I follow this example: [Scheduling algorithm for a round-robin tournament?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648512/scheduling-algorithm-for-a-round-robin-tournament) to create round robin tournament. But there is one problem which I have. Lets say we have tournament in table tennis and I want to improve this algorithm by changing their position. Player 1 still plays on table 1 which I dont want. All player should change their table as much as possible and do not play on the same table 2 and more round in row

Answer (score 1):

Once you've decided who is to play whom in the given round, randomly assign the pairs of players to tables.

A single [random shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) per round will do the trick.

This way, no one will get any systematic advantage by repeatedly playing at the same table.

Comment: random is not options for me because there is still small chance that player 1 will play all game on table 1. I need there some system