# algorithm to calculate number pair sequence

Tags: algorithm

I need to calculate a sequence of numbers (similar to Sudoku) to match teams to play each other.

I need to create a matrix for 8 and 9 teams and can't figure out the formula.  I have to believe this is really simple, but I have no idea what to search for to find it.

Here is a working version for 7 teams:

team      |1  2   3   4   5   6   7 
 ====================
week 1  |      7   6   5   4   3   2
week 2  | 7    5   6   3   4   1
week 3  | 6 5      7   2   1   4
week 4  | 5 6   7      1   2   3
week 5  | 4 3   2   1      7   6
week 6  | 3 4   1   2   7      5
week 7  | 2 1   4   3   6   5

So for the first week, team 1 doesn't play (no available partner), team 2 plays team 7, team 3 plays team 6, etc.
For week 2, team 1 plays team 7, etc.

No team may play the other team.  The event continues for as many weeks as we have teams, so 8 teams would play for 8 weeks.

Each team should play another team once and only once.  They can't play themselves (hence the blank entry in each row.

Note that the upper right triangle is a mirror of the bottom left triangle, but that still didn't help me determine the formula.

My guess is that if I spent enough hours, I could figure out the formula.  But since this has to have been done a few million times by people over the ages, I am guessing that it's a well known algorithm and I just need to find someone who knows the name (so I can look it up) or can tell me what it is so I can create this for a friend who needs it.

Thanks!

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648512/scheduling-algorithm-for-a-round-robin-tournament

Comment: search for "Round-Robin Tournament Scheduling"

Comment: Don't worry, this is not as simple as it first seems. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer so far is from Dennis Meng (I can't comment, so I have to use an answer).  That link pointed me to a question where the answer worked, sort of.  I don't have an algorithym yet, but the methodology worked adequately.  I have my rows and columns.  It doesn't provide me with a "mirror" image the way the example does.  But it does give me a unique team for each week.  I am hoping that will be enough.

I just used excel to lay it out as that was faster than trying to figure out the logic, write the code, and get a nice formatted result - especially since I only seem to need to do it once.

But if it turns out I need to do it again, I will write a simple application and post it here.

Of course, it would be great if I could get the routine that generated the above matrix....

Of course, that also leads me to another issue.  How can I mark Dennis' comment as the answer???? He deserves the credit (unless someone chimes in with the mirror solution....)

Oh well, thanks Dennis!

Comment: `"I can't comment"` - As far as I know, you can comment on your own posts and answers to your questions. **Although**, linking to another question is not an answer. The question should simply be marked as a duplicate and that should be the end of it. You can flag your question as a duplicate (by clicking the `flag` button below the question), which will bring it to the attention of higher reputation users, who can mark it as such it if they agree.

Comment: I thought so too, but it wouldn't let me at the time... Now it does, weird.

Comment: Also, the thread the Dennis pointed me to helped me figure it out, it wasn't really an answer - it just made it easier.  I still don't have the mirror ability, but I think I can get by with what I do have.  So there isn't a duplicate question issue.