# Pairing Algorithm

Tags: node.js, algorithm, pattern-matching

I am trying to find an effective approach for generating unique pairings. For example I have a set of Users

[ John, Joe, Tim, Fred, Todd, Kevin ]

I am trying to come up with a program such that each time I run it it will give everyone a different pair

For Example

## 1st run

John Joe
Tim Fred
Todd Kevin

## 2nd Run

John Tim
Joe Fred
Kevin Todd

and so on

Im trying to make it such that this algorithm does not repeat a pair until all pairs have gone through

This is not for hw!!! this is for my own personal project.

I am trying to use Node.js for this any advice would be great!!!

Comment: Can't you just create a random permutation of the list (using Fisher-Yates shuffle, for example) and then split elements into pairs?

Comment: I think you can, Create all permutations, store it in your back-end, randomly select from previously non selected ones based on user token

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheduling algorithm for a round-robin tournament?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648512/scheduling-algorithm-for-a-round-robin-tournament)