# Find unique partitions from combinations of certain size

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations, partition

I am trying to break a list of integers (say `elements`) into all of its possible partitions with combinations of the same size (say `n`), where the combinations are unique across different partitions, not just within the same partition.

The use case is that I have a list of people, and I need to match them so they all meet each other exactly once, in the minimum amount of time. So for a list of 10 people meeting weekly, and meetings of 1:1 (2 people in each combination), they can all meet each other in 9 weeks.

A solution that can take any combination size is ideal, but one that only works for size 2 is also great.

#### Example

For example, if the list is `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`.
We can't have both of these partitions:

```
[1,2], [3,5], [4,6]
[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
```

because then `[1,2]` is found twice...

A possible result (or the only? not sure) is:

```
1: [1,2], [3,4], [5,6]
2: [1,3], [2,5], [4,6]
3: [1,4], [2,6], [3,5]
4: [1,5], [2,4], [3,6]
5: [1,6], [2,3], [4,5]
```

#### What I tried?

This is very naive and does not work, because it ends up doing something like this:

```
1: [1,2], [3,5], [4,6]
2: [1,3], [2,5],  ???  -> Can't do [4,6] again!
```

It basically gets all possible combinations of a certain size, then tries to make the partitions from them.

```swift
var result = [Partition<T>]()
var combinations = elements.combinations(ofCount: 2)

while !combinations.isEmpty {

    var pairs = [Pair<T>]()
    var elementsLeft = elements

    while elementsLeft.count > 1 {
        let aPair = combinations.first { elementsLeft.contains($0.x) && elementsLeft.contains($0.y) }!
        combinations.remove(aPair)
        elementsLeft.remove(aPair.x)
        elementsLeft.remove(aPair.y)
        pairs.append(aPair)
    }

    let partition = Partition(matches: pairs, unmatched: Array(elementsLeft))
    result.append(partition)
}

return result
```

(I am using Swift, but will happily take advice in any language or pseudo logic! As long as it avoids things I am not sure how to translate like Python's `yield` etc.)

I also know of a way to get partitions with combinations of 2 where each partition has exactly 1 duplicated combination. Going back to the use case, it means I will match a list of 6 people in 6 weeks (instead of 5), and that there will be weeks where a couple of people won't have a meeting. That solution can be easily shown in a small table (letters are elements/people in the list, numbers are partition/week number). It essentially just involves shifting the numbers up by 1 row in each column, ignoring pairs of an element with itself…

I can't use this solution because it means having another partition (ie, one more week)...

```
|   | A | B | C | D | E | F |
|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
| A |   | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| B | 2 |   | 4 | 5 | 6 | 1 |
| C | 3 | 4 |   | 6 | 1 | 2 |
| D | 4 | 5 | 6 |   | 2 | 3 |
| E | 5 | 6 | 1 | 2 |   | 4 |
| F | 6 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |   |

eg
week 1: [F,B], [E,C] (where [A,D] "unmatched")
week 2: [A,B], [C,F], [D,E]
// ...
```

Comment: Can the number of participants be odd?

Comment: yes, then each partition has "leftover", so eg in a list of 7 you would have 6 (I think?) partitions where each of the elements is left in one of the partitions

Comment: just use 2 loop, and match if 2 values are not equal

Comment: @Nur that doesn't solve the problem...

Comment: Does [Round Robin Scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648512/scheduling-algorithm-for-a-round-robin-tournament/6649732#6649732) work for you?

Comment: I think it does!! I did not know this is how it's called, thank you! I will run a few tests to ensure this covers it and write the solution here, unless you want to add it I'll happily accept your answer (:

Comment: If that old answer is the exact answer to this question then this question is a duplicate, and should be closed. Unless you want the answer for tuples too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer **for a combination size of 2** is an implementation of the Round Robin algorithm, as mentioned by @RaffleBuffle in the comment.

Below is an implementation in Swift:

```swift
func roundRobin(teams n: Int) -> [[[Int]]] {
    var rounds = [[[Int]]]()
    var aRound = [[Int]]()
    var aMatch = [Int]()
    for r in 1..<n {
        for i in 1...n/2 {
            if (i == 1) {
                aMatch.append(1)
                aMatch.append((n-1+r-1) % (n-1) + 2)
            } else {
                aMatch.append((r+i-2) % (n-1) + 2)
                aMatch.append((n-1+r-i) % (n-1) + 2)
            }
            aRound.append(aMatch)
            aMatch = []
        }
        rounds.append(aRound)
        aRound = []
    }
    return rounds
}
```

We can then get the results:

```swift
for round in roundRobin(teams: 12) {
    print(round)
}
```

Which prints:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 12], [4, 11], [5, 10], [6, 9], [7, 8]]
[[1, 3], [4, 2], [5, 12], [6, 11], [7, 10], [8, 9]]
[[1, 4], [5, 3], [6, 2], [7, 12], [8, 11], [9, 10]]
[[1, 5], [6, 4], [7, 3], [8, 2], [9, 12], [10, 11]]
[[1, 6], [7, 5], [8, 4], [9, 3], [10, 2], [11, 12]]
[[1, 7], [8, 6], [9, 5], [10, 4], [11, 3], [12, 2]]
[[1, 8], [9, 7], [10, 6], [11, 5], [12, 4], [2, 3]]
[[1, 9], [10, 8], [11, 7], [12, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]]
[[1, 10], [11, 9], [12, 8], [2, 7], [3, 6], [4, 5]]
[[1, 11], [12, 10], [2, 9], [3, 8], [4, 7], [5, 6]]
[[1, 12], [2, 11], [3, 10], [4, 9], [5, 8], [6, 7]]
```