Return all possible matchups for a set of 32 teams who have a smaller subset of allowable opponents
I'm having a problem writing an algorithm to return all possible valid matchups for a set of 32 teams. The rules are:

The schedule is for only one game per pair of teams. This does not need to be a round robin as the teams do not all play each other. The algorithm needs to be all valid possibilities of the 16 games between the 32 teams, but not have any duplicated schedules (with games in different indexes, for example)
Home/away does not matter and is not applicable here
Each team only has a subset of 14 other teams that they are eligible to play.
Teams must have an opponent. If a version of the schedule does not end up with all teams having a match, it is invalid and shouldn't be returned.

The actual data for the teams and allowable opponents for each team is below:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "opponents": [
      8,
      25,
      28,
      2,
      20,
      23,
      19,
      13,
      10,
      4,
      21,
      14,
      32,
      7,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "opponents": [
      20,
      21,
      32,
      18,
      25,
      28,
      31,
      22,
      23,
      8,
      30,
      11,
      1,
      12,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "opponents": [
      26,
      6,
      29,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      23,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      31,
      22,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "opponents": [
      14,
      23,
      19,
      8,
      18,
      1,
      31,
      10,
      30,
      11,
      25,
      28,
      26,
      20,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "opponents": [
      10,
      24,
      9,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      11,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      19,
      28,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "opponents": [
      26,
      3,
      29,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      14,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      18,
      27,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "opponents": [
      16,
      22,
      27,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      1,
      26,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      20,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "opponents": [
      25,
      1,
      28,
      2,
      20,
      23,
      19,
      12,
      9,
      4,
      21,
      14,
      32,
      22,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "opponents": [
      5,
      10,
      24,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      31,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      23,
      8,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "opponents": [
      5,
      24,
      9,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      30,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      4,
      1,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "opponents": [
      30,
      18,
      31,
      4,
      2,
      20,
      14,
      29,
      21,
      32,
      23,
      19,
      5,
      17,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 12,
    "opponents": [
      13,
      17,
      15,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      2,
      31,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      8,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 13,
    "opponents": [
      17,
      15,
      12,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      20,
      30,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      1,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 14,
    "opponents": [
      4,
      23,
      19,
      8,
      18,
      1,
      31,
      24,
      30,
      11,
      25,
      28,
      6,
      21,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 15,
    "opponents": [
      13,
      17,
      12,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      21,
      18,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      25,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 16,
    "opponents": [
      22,
      27,
      7,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      28,
      29,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      32,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 17,
    "opponents": [
      13,
      15,
      12,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      32,
      11,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      28,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 18,
    "opponents": [
      30,
      11,
      31,
      21,
      32,
      23,
      19,
      6,
      4,
      2,
      20,
      14,
      24,
      15,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 19,
    "opponents": [
      4,
      14,
      23,
      30,
      11,
      25,
      28,
      5,
      8,
      18,
      1,
      31,
      29,
      32,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 20,
    "opponents": [
      2,
      21,
      32,
      18,
      25,
      28,
      31,
      7,
      4,
      8,
      30,
      11,
      1,
      13,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 21,
    "opponents": [
      2,
      20,
      32,
      8,
      30,
      11,
      1,
      27,
      14,
      18,
      25,
      28,
      31,
      15,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 22,
    "opponents": [
      16,
      27,
      7,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      8,
      3,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      2,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 23,
    "opponents": [
      4,
      14,
      19,
      30,
      11,
      25,
      28,
      9,
      8,
      18,
      1,
      31,
      3,
      2,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 24,
    "opponents": [
      5,
      10,
      9,
      16,
      22,
      6,
      29,
      18,
      26,
      3,
      27,
      7,
      14,
      25,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 25,
    "opponents": [
      8,
      1,
      28,
      4,
      21,
      14,
      32,
      15,
      24,
      2,
      20,
      23,
      19,
      27,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "opponents": [
      3,
      6,
      29,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      4,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      30,
      7,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 27,
    "opponents": [
      16,
      22,
      7,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      25,
      6,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      21,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 28,
    "opponents": [
      8,
      25,
      1,
      4,
      21,
      14,
      32,
      17,
      5,
      2,
      20,
      23,
      19,
      16,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 29,
    "opponents": [
      26,
      3,
      6,
      13,
      10,
      9,
      17,
      19,
      5,
      24,
      15,
      12,
      11,
      16,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "opponents": [
      11,
      18,
      31,
      4,
      2,
      20,
      14,
      26,
      21,
      32,
      23,
      19,
      10,
      13,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 31,
    "opponents": [
      30,
      11,
      18,
      21,
      32,
      23,
      19,
      3,
      4,
      2,
      20,
      14,
      9,
      12,
    ],
  },
  {
    "id": 32,
    "opponents": [
      2,
      20,
      21,
      8,
      30,
      11,
      1,
      16,
      19,
      18,
      25,
      28,
      31,
      17,
    ],
  },
]

I'm thinking there probably is a recursive solution that would be elegant for this, but I really am having a problem wrapping my head around it or finding the appropriately named algorithm that already exists.
I will be implementing this using javascript but obviously the algorithm is language independent. But any examples specifically in javascript/using javascript operators etc would help.

Are you fairly certain that this will be a tractable number of results?  It seems likely that the count would be astronomical.  Also do you have any guarantee that there will be any results at all?  If team1 has opponents of [team2, team3, ..., team15], but none of team2, team3, ...team15 has team1 as an opponent, then there will be no solutions.

The total number of possible team combinations is 448 and each valid schedule will contain 16 of those so I don't think the numbers are ridiculous due to the restrictions (but if I'm wrong I'd like to know that). There will be guaranteed results as the available opponents are not random. There will never be a case where there are no solutions. I'm most interested in weeding out the invalid schedules (where picking certain matchups would leave a team with no valid matchup at the end since the only other team left is not a valid opponent for that particular team)

Thus is a classic problem and a solution can be found here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648512/scheduling-algorithm-for-a-round-robin-tournament (check out the accepted answer there).

@CarstenMassmann in a round robin every team plays every other team, that is not the case here. For clarity, I have updated the data to the actual data so it's clearer.

I get a very large number for the number of possible (unrestricted) pairings: 32! / (2 ^ 16) / 16! (191898783962510620, over 1.9e17).  Arrange the 32 numbers in any permutation (32!), think of these as sixteen sequential pairs, and allow for each pair to be sorted either way (2 ^ 16), and then, and allow the pairs to be permuted in any order (16!).  Is there something wrong with this logic?  If, OTOH, you're looking simply to find a single valid round, I think a simple backtracking algorithm would be straightforward.

This can be accomplished by creating a nested loop that takes every pairing of a team and its opponent and adds it to the schedule if that pairing is not already included on the schedule. Here's an example:


const teams =  [
  teamId1 = {
    id: "teamId1",
    opponents: ["teamId2", "teamId3", "teamId5", "teamId8", "teamId14"] // length 14
  },
  teamId2 = {
    id: "teamId2",
    opponents: ["teamId1", "teamId3", "teamId6", "teamId11", "teamId12"] // length 14
  }
] // length 32

// Empty aray to store the schedule
const schedule  = [];

// Loop through initial array
teams.forEach(team => {
  // Loop  through subarray of opponents of team
  team.opponents.forEach(opponent => {
    // Make sure that [team, opp] is not already included in schedule
    if (
      !(schedule.includes([team.id, opponent]))
      && !(schedule.includes([opponent, team.id]))
    ) {
      // add pairing to schedule
      schedule.push([team.id, opponent]);
    }
  })
})

console.log(schedule);



EDIT:
In response to your comment below, here's a version of the above code that creates a new permutation for each element in the array:


const teams =  [
  teamId1 = {
    id: "teamId1",
    opponents: ["teamId2", "teamId3", "teamId5", "teamId8", "teamId14"] // length 14
  },
  teamId2 = {
    id: "teamId2",
    opponents: ["teamId1", "teamId3", "teamId6", "teamId11", "teamId12"] // length 14
  }
] // length 32

// Empty array to store the schedule
const schedule  = [];

// Loop through initial array
teams.forEach(team => {
  // Array for each permutation
  const permutation = [];

  // To store the final result of the array
  const finalSchedule = [];

  // Create new array to flatten teamIdn with its opponents
  const allTeams = [team.id, ...team.opponents]
  // Loop through teams array to look for parings
  allTeams.forEach(team1 => {
    // Nested loop to explore every possible pairing
    allTeams.forEach(team2 => {
      // Possible pairings
      const pair1 = [team1, team2];
      const pair2 = [team2, team1];
      // Make sure that pairing or equivalent pairing is not already included in schedule
      if (
        !(permutation.includes(pair1))
        && !(permutation.includes(pair2))
        && schedule.every(i => !(i.includes(pair1)))
        && schedule.every(i => !(i.includes(pair2)))
        && team1 !== team2
      ) {
        // add pairing to schedule
        permutation.push(pair1);
      }

      // Filter the permutations so that no one team can play twice
      permutation.forEach(item => {
        if (
          !(finalSchedule.flat().includes(item[0]))
          && !(finalSchedule.flat().includes(item[1]))
        ) { 
          finalSchedule.push(item) 
        }
      })
      
    })
  })
  schedule.push(finalSchedule);
})

console.log(schedule);




By matchup I meant every possible permutation of teams playing each other. So there would be multiple schedules of 16 games. What you have here returns every possible team combination without the corresponding other teams games. What would the loop look like using these results to create individual schedules?
Also I don't think includes works with arrays as the target as running this code still returns the duplicate matchups. I can fix that, though.

Regarding your 1st point: could you elaborate on what you mean by "every possible permutation of teams playing each other"? I'm not sure if I understand what that means. Perhaps it's relevant that I don't watch any sports.
Regarding the 2nd point: includes should work as far as I can tell -- the issue was with the conditional statement, which checked if [team, opponent] or [opponent, team] are included in the schedule array, rather than if [team.id, opponent] or [opponent, team.id] are included. I've edited the original comment to fix that. There shouldn't be any duplicates now.

So for example a permutation of the schedule would be one combination of all 16 teams playing each other i.e. [["teamId1", "teamId2"], ["teamid3", "teamid4"], ["teamId5", "teamId12"], ...etc] which would represent team1 vs team2, team3 vs team4, etc. Another permutation would be  [["teamId1", "teamId5"], ["teamid2", "teamid6"], ["teamId7", "teamId8"], ...etc] if that makes sense.

I understand what you mean by permutation in that sense, I was more wondering how you define each permutation. Because there seems to be many ways to define a given permutation, e.g. it could be every unique pairing of teams, every unique paring of teams that includes a specific team, etc. Given what you've said, I'm going to guess that you want to define each permutation so that there is one permutation for each element in the array, and each permutation consists of all unique parings of teams within that element. And you want no duplicate parings, even between permutations. Is that correct?

A permutation is an array of length 16, each element in the array is an array of 2 team Ids and no team ids can be repeated in one permutation. So every possible version of that that exists with the given values in the algorithm in your original answer.

Also, the same teams in a different index of the array would be considered a duplicate. The uniqueness is just based on any 2 teams playing each other. Doesn't matter where in the array or if one is listed first or not. Team A vs Team B is all I care about.

I think we are talking past one another, but I tried to take a crack at it anyway. I edited my original comment so that the algorithm does what I think you want it to do -- let me know if this works.

Just saw your other comment. I changed the code so that it also screens for duplicates in other permutations, too.

That's update doesn't do it, it just appears to separate each opponent into separate permutations (which is already expressed in the original data) . I have updated my question with the actual data I expect to use so you can see for yourself.

I don't know if the data would help, because the issue seems to me to be that the term 'permutation' is being used ambiguously (i.e. it's not entirely clear what you want the output/return value of this algorithm to be). Before I was defining the permutation as any pairing of teams where the id property of the object is included in that pairing. Since that didn't do the trick, I have edited the code to define a permutation as all unique pairings of teams for a given element in the top array. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

I'll try and explain it in real terms so it makes sense. Every id represents and team and all 32 teams are going to play once at the exact same time against a single opponent (so 16 games happening at once) I need all possible 16 matchups where this could happen. Your original response was halfway there by defining the possible matchups, but now the results your code return include the same team in the same grouping which would be impossible to do because a team cannot play two tames at once. I'm pretty sure the solution involves recursion and cannot easily be done in a simple loop.

Okay, that's helpful, thank you. I think I understand what you are going for now. I've changed it so no one team can appear more than once in a given permutation. I hope that's helpful.

The following code iterates over all possible combinations. There is a slight error, that combinations may be output several times consecutively, so you can either fix the bug, or check consecutively answers for equality.
The programming concept for this algorithm is called Backtracking, which I apply to a (sorted) list of possible matches.
export interface Team {
  id: number;
  opponents: number[];
};

export const team_predef: Team[] = []; // Put your team definition here


type Match = [number, number];

class GenerateMatchups {
  // Preparation, filled by constructot
  possibleMatches: Match[];
  teamIds: number[];
  teamIndexInPossibleMatches: number[];

  // State for the matches
  stateMatches: Match[];
  stateTeamIndex: number[];
  stateTeamsWithMatch: Set<number>;
  stateDepth: number;
  /// true => We are currently searching for matches, false we deconstruct to find a new match
  stateInsert: boolean;
  constructor(teams: Team[]) {
    // Team id must be ascending
    this.possibleMatches = [];
    this.teamIds = [];
    this.teamIndexInPossibleMatches = [];
    this.stateTeamsWithMatch = new Set([]);
    this.stateInsert = true; // true ==
    for (const t of teams) {
      this.teamIds.push(t.id);
      // Store where the matches of this team begin
      this.teamIndexInPossibleMatches.push(this.possibleMatches.length);
      // Sort for nicer output
      t.opponents.sort();
      for (const o of t.opponents) {
        // Prevent double inserts [o, t.id] is the same match as [t.id, o]
        if (t.id < o) {
          this.possibleMatches.push([t.id, o]);
        }
      }
    }
    // Final size of possibleMatches at the end
    this.teamIndexInPossibleMatches.push(this.possibleMatches.length);

    this.stateTeamIndex = this.teamIndexInPossibleMatches;
    // TODO Checks for special cases with impossible matches, etc.

  }

  *RecursiveGetNext(matches: Match[] = [], index = 0, usedTeams = new Set<number>([])) {
    if (index < this.teamIds.length) {

      if (matches.length == this.teamIds.length / 2) {
        // Return a copy
        yield [...matches.map(m => [...m])];
      }
      if (usedTeams.has(this.teamIds[index])) {
        for (let x of this.RecursiveGetNext(matches, index + 1, usedTeams)) {
          yield x;
        }
      } else {
        for (let indexMatch = this.teamIndexInPossibleMatches[index];
          indexMatch < this.teamIndexInPossibleMatches[index + 1];
          ++indexMatch) {
          const m = this.possibleMatches[indexMatch];
          if (usedTeams.has(m[0]) || usedTeams.has(m[1])) {
            // Match is not possible, try the next one
            continue;
          }
          matches.push(m);
          usedTeams.add(m[0]);
          usedTeams.add(m[1]);
          for (let x of this.RecursiveGetNext(matches, index + 1, usedTeams)) {
            yield x;
          }
          matches.pop();
          usedTeams.delete(m[0]);
          usedTeams.delete(m[1]);
        }
      }
    }
  }


};


const genMatchups = new GenerateMatchups(team_predef);

let i = 0;
for(const matchup of genMatchups.RecursiveGetNext())
{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(matchup));
  if(++i > 100) // Limit the number of outputs for debugging
  {
    break;
  }
}



Ahh thanks for the algorithm name. This is actually very similar to the code I got chat gpt to generate for me and it actually put a comment in there for the backtracking.

A brute force algo: put all combinations in buckets (if there's no teams from a pair in a bucket, add the pair):


const teams = Array.from({length:32}, (_,i) => i+1);

const rounds = [];

for(let i=0;i<teams.length;i++){
  for(let j=i+1;j<teams.length;j++){
    let n = 0;
    while(true){
      const {set, matches} = (rounds[n++] ??= {matches:[], set: new Set});
      if(!(set.has(i) || set.has(j)) && matches.length < teams.length/2){
        set.add(i), set.add(j);
        matches.push([teams[i], teams[j]]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

rounds.map(r => r.matches).forEach(m => console.log(JSON.stringify(m)+'\n'));



There's definitely a pattern here, that could be recreated without Set. But given a small data set (32 teams), making the algo perfect won't gain much time in the run time.
